After Inheritence Sklearn Ridge model acts silly, while with composition it works
I was doing inheritance of class sklearn.linear_model.Ridge. I have created child class as follow:
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        super().__init__(alpha = 0.5) 
        
        super().fit(X, y)
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return super().predict(X)
        
    
    def show_accuracy(nafs):
        pass

The error I am getting is:
AttributeError: 'RidgeRegression' object has no attribute 'X'
Interestingly, if I compose the Ridge(), instead of inheritance, it works smoothly.
I have tried to inherit the class Ridge from sklearn.linear_model. However, it shows unclear error like Attribute error and so on. However, composition of the same class works normally.

Always provide the full error traceback. Ideally, provide a [mre] (here, some toy dataset, and the code that actually throws the error: is it class instantiation, or fitting, or...?). And the composition approach that succeeds might be when including.
